# How we can download a file from Azure Storage to our local browser as an download attachment in React + Java script

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, express

On click of a button Download, the file should get downloaded as a download attachment in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button>Download File</button>
```

Storage connection:

```
getToAzureStorage = (blobName, containerName) => {
const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(`https://${storageAcc}.blob.core.windows.net${sas}`);
const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
const blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(blobName);
const downloadFileURL = blobClient.url;
return {
    downloadFileURL,
}
```

};

```
app.get('/download', (req, resp) => {
    const {bucketlink, bucketName} = req.query;
    const {downloadFileURL} = getToAzureStorage(bucketlink, bucketName);
    https.get(downloadFileURL, (stream) => {
        resp.setHeader('Content-disposition', `attachment; filename=${bucketlink}`);
        stream.pipe(resp);
    });
});
```